# List Google Cloud resources sorted by time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am listing my compute disks as follows:

```
▶ gcloud compute disks list
NAME                                                             LOCATION    LOCATION_SCOPE  SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
foobar                                                           us-east4-b  zone            50       pd-standard  READY
jenkins-kos-pd                                                   us-east4-b  zone            100      pd-standard  READY
```

I want to list them by creation time. I was unable to find such an option and running

```
gcloud compute disks list --format="value(name)" --sort-by=TIME --limit=1
```

yields unpredictable results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `creationTimestamp` as a sort parameter :

```
gcloud compute disks list \
    --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)" \
    --sort-by=creationTimestamp
```

Note that you can sort them by descending order by adding a `~` in front of `creationTimestamp` :

```
gcloud compute disks list \
    --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)" \
    --sort-by=~creationTimestamp
```